# Incrementing the Speed with Every Button Click

Tags: c#

I have a working application that compiles and everything. The two buttons work, however I need them to add/decrease 5 from the speed with every single click and currently they will only let me click once and accelerate gives me an answer of 5 for speed, while decelerate gives -5. How can I change this to allow for each button to be clicked and the speed update more than once?

Here is the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private Car myCar;

public Form1()
{
myCar = new Car();

InitializeComponent();
}


private void GetCarData()
{

try {
myCar.Make = txtMake.Text;

myCar.Year = int.Parse(txtModel.Text);

myCar.Speed = 0;

}
            catch (Exception ex)
{
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Must enter a valid make and year model for the car. ", ex.Message, "\r\n", ex.StackTrace));
} 

}

private void btnAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GetCarData();
myCar.AccSpeed(5);
lblAnswer.Text = " Your car is a " + myCar.Year + " " + myCar.Make + " and it is traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ";
}
private void btnBrake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GetCarData();
myCar.DecSpeed(5);
lblAnswer.Text = " Your car is a " + myCar.Year + " " + myCar.Make + " and it is traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ";
}


}
}
```

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
class Car
{
private int year;
private string make;
private int speed;

public Car()
{
    this.year = 1994;
    this.make = "Ford";
    this.speed = 0;
}

public Car(string make, int year, int speed)
{
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.speed = speed;
}

public string Make
{
    get { return make; }
    set { make = value; }
}

public int Year
{
    get { return year; }
    set { year = value; }
}

public int Speed
{
    get { return speed; }
    set { speed = value; }
}

public void AccSpeed(int speedIncrement)
{
    //Add check for speed limit ranges
    Speed += speedIncrement;
}

public void DecSpeed(int speedDecrement)
{
    //Add check for speed limit ranges
    Speed -= speedDecrement;
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is probably homework I'll just give hints. With both click functions, the first call you make is to `GetCarData()`. Inside `GetCarData()`, you're calling `myCar.Speed = 0;`, so it's not surprising that you're going back to square one with each click.

Assuming that you want only one instance of `Car` for your entire application, you just need to modify the insides of `GetCarData()` to do (or *not* do) what you want. Just a few tweaks in that function, which I'll let you experiment with, and you'll be good to go.

However, if you want multiple `Car` objects in your app, you're going to need to modify it to have some kind of `List` (or better yet, an `IDictionary`).